# How to make Multiple date selector in one Date Picker in Android Studio using Java?

Tags: java, android-studio

How to make a date picker with multiple date selecting options in Android Studio using Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
implementation 'com.savvi.datepicker:rangepicker:1.3.0'
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.savvi.rangedatepicker.CalendarPickerView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        app:tsquare_orientation_horizontal="false"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_selected_dates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Selected Dates"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="229dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="447dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dateselected"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

````
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.savvi.rangedatepicker.CalendarPickerView;
import com.savvi.rangedatepicker.SubTitle;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CalendarPickerView calendar;
    Button button;
    private TextView datesSelected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datesSelected=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateselected);

        final Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);

        final Calendar lastYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        lastYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, - 10);

        calendar = findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
        button = findViewById(R.id.get_selected_dates);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(4);

        //calendar.deactivateDates(list);
        ArrayList<Date> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        calendar.init(lastYear.getTime(), nextYear.getTime(), new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, YYYY", Locale.getDefault())) //
                .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        calendar.scrollToDate(new Date());

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "list " + calendar.getSelectedDates(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                datesSelected.setText("");
                ArrayList<Date>selectedDates = (ArrayList<Date>)calendar.getSelectedDates();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                for(int i = 0; i< selectedDates.size(); i++)
                {
                    Date tempDate = selectedDates.get(i);
                    String formattedDate = sdf.format(tempDate);
                    datesSelected.append(formattedDate);
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "list " + formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Following if is added to avoid adding comma after the last date.
                    datesSelected.append("<br/>");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<SubTitle> getSubTitles() {
        final ArrayList<SubTitle> subTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        final Calendar tmrw = Calendar.getInstance();
        tmrw.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        subTitles.add(new SubTitle(tmrw.getTime(), "₹1000"));
        return subTitles;
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

With naitive `DatePicker` you can't.

if you want multiple select, you can use library.

you can try to use [this library](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker) or [libraries](https://github.com/savvisingh/DateRangePicker)

Comment: if my answer true, please check Answer Accepted